# Updating SqlCipher from 1.1 to 2.2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlcipher

I am trying to update the sqlcipher from version 1.1 to 2.2.2. The new version of the sqlcipher works fine in a fresh install or when i run it from eclipse. But when I update the app which was previously using v1.1 sqlcipher with new v2.2.2, the library doesn't load properly. When i call the SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this), the app crashes. i get the below info in the logcat

09-11 11:21:56.887: I/Database(26277): JNI_OnLoad called

09-11 11:21:56.887: I/Database(26277): JNI_OnLoad register methods

09-11 11:21:56.887: E/Database(26277): Can't find SQLiteDatabase.mNativeHandle

09-11 11:21:56.887: E/Cursor(26277): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteCompiledSql

09-11 11:21:56.887: E/Cursor(26277): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteQuery

09-11 11:21:56.887: E/Cursor(26277): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteProgram

09-11 11:21:56.887: E/Cursor(26277): Can't find net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteStatement

09-11 11:21:56.887: E/CursorWindow(26277): Can't find net/sqlcipher/CursorWindow

09-11 11:21:56.903: W/dalvikvm(26277): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b73930)

update: i am using proguard. when i turned off proguard, the SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this) worked fine. But this time i am not able to open the encrypted database. I am passing the same correct password to open the database.

09-11 14:21:48.950: I/Database(31543): sqlite returned: error code = 26, msg = file is encrypted or is not a database

09-11 14:21:48.950: E/Database(31543): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543): net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2102)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1968)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:901)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:944)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:107)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at alc.rhapsody.mdd.database.DatabaseAdapter.openDatabase(DatabaseAdapter.java:234)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at alc.rhapsody.mdd.presenter.SplashViewPresenter.getAdmissionAccess(SplashViewPresenter.java:152)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at alc.rhapsody.mdd.presenter.SplashViewPresenter.access$2(SplashViewPresenter.java:99)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at alc.rhapsody.mdd.presenter.SplashViewPresenter$AdmissionCtrl.doInBackground(SplashViewPresenter.java:235)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at alc.rhapsody.mdd.presenter.SplashViewPresenter$AdmissionCtrl.doInBackground(SplashViewPresenter.java:1)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)

09-11 14:21:48.965: E/Database(31543):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Answer (score 0):

Are u providing password for the file, seems like you havent and once you do provide the database also use the NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS in the flags

Comment: i am passing the password. How ever now i have resolved the issue with help from the sqlcipher developer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a link or something that clarifies the solution.